# how to extract high frequency phrase

Tags: data-mining, dataset, statistics, text-mining

This is the corpus

```
abcdef
abcd
xabcd
b
bcef
ef
aef
```

what I want to extract is `abcd`, `ef`, then I try to count all n-grams:

```
abcdef 1
abcd 3
abc 3
...
```

My question is how to distinguish `abcd` with `abcdef` and `abc`, since `abcdef` just appear once, and `abc` is the sub-string of 'abcd'. Of course, I can filter with this two conditions, but just want to know any existing algorithm target on solving this problem.

Comment: which functionality do you want?  In "abcdef" do you want to count "a", "ab", "bc", ..... "abcdef", or do you want it to only show up as "abcdef"?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I only want to extract `abcd` here, and `ef` maybe. since `abcdef` is not a `high frequency` phrase, and `a` or `ab` or `abc` is most likely a sub-string of the high frequency phrase `abcd`.

Comment: I see - it was the "maybe" piece that was confusing. It sounded like you had predefined substrings you cared about/wanted to ignore, not just based on frequencies

Comment: Most likely? And if there were two abcdef?  Define the rules.

Comment: Please can @YuwenYan clarify whether the provided solutions have helped by rating them or marking the problem as solved?

Comment: @Emre no, I'm still looking for the solution...

Comment: Nobody seems to clearly understand what you want, so please can you rephrase the question "how to distinguish abcd with abcdef and abc, since abcdef just appear once, and abc is the sub-string of 'abcd'", and complete the output for your given input list?

Answer (score 1):

This uses python and NLTK

```
import nltk

text = """abcdef
abcd
xabcd
b
bcef
ef
aef
"""

def tokens(lines):
    for line in lines:
        for n in range(1, len(line)):
            ts = nltk.ngrams(line, n)
            for t in ts: yield str.join('', t) 
        yield line

ts = tokens(text.splitlines())
freq = nltk.FreqDist(ts)
print(freq.most_common())
# [('b', 5), ('c', 4), ('ef', 4), ('bc', 4), ('e', 4)...
```

There are other solutions, of course, but I think this meets your criteria. You may need to optimize if your lines are huge as this will create every possible n-gram.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the goal of the procedure you are asking about.

You might be interested in [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding)

Huffman codes are used for text compression.
They identify high frequency sequences and assign to them short codes, getting a a reduction in the overall text size.

The tree constructed for the code might help you with what you look for.

As an extra bonus, it is a classical algorithm so you will be able to find many implementations for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of data you could split your words into sentences of single letters and treat each sentence as a separate document. Then feed it into CountVectorizer from sklearn to create a sparse matrix containing vectors for ngrams of length from 2 to max length. Use binary=True to avoid double counting of a repeating pattern inside the word. Last step is to calculate which columns of the matrix have the highest number of 'ones' and look up which ngrams that were from the vectorizer dictionary.